# Can the Oracle JRE be downloaded from the oracle website and run from an automated computer program

Tags: java

Can a computer program download the oracle jre from the Oracle website, unzip it and run java without prompting the user to accept the Oracle license?

Comment: Yes. But I'm not sure how.

Comment: [Oracle JRE Installer Options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/silent-136552.html)